# Error in setting up Fuchsia

Tags: linux-kernel, fuchsia

I was trying to build Fuchsia. During importing the source, it says to add `/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin` to my `PATH`. I did it but the `ERROR` says,

```
Updating all projects
ERROR: 'git fetch -p origin' failed:
stdout:

stderr:
fatal: unable to access 'https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/github.com/kr/fs/': gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

command fail error: exit status 128

Wait for 5s before next attempt...: Fetching for /home/amim/fuchsia/third_party/golibs/github.com/kr/fs

Attempt 2/3: Fetching for /home/amim/fuchsia/third_party/golibs/github.com/kr/fs

ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

Though there were errors, I tried the `jiri` command and it works. And then, I tried `fx` that was located in `scripts/fx`, it says `Cannot find Platform Source Tree containing /home/amim`

here is my PATH variable:
`/home/amim/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle/db/bin:/flutter/flutter/bin:/home/amim/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:/flutter/flutter/bin:/home/amim/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:/home/amim/fuchsia/scripts`

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

I ran fx from the fuschia directory and it works, it seems that fx is expecting you to already be in that directory